# java native2ascii not converting properties file correctly

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have the following text in a properties file:

> Asegúrese de que los datos

I am trying to convert the text into ascii but the character **ú** is being converted to **\ufffd** which means an invalid character instead of the valid ascii equivalent.

The command I am using the convert the text is:

> native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 x.properties y.properties

Do you know what I am doing wrong and what could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Is your original file saved in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: That was the problem, the file was saved in ANSI instead of UTF-8. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of people who encounter the same issue, the problem was, that the file was saved in ANSI instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem found.

It works well with windows but fails on linux.

You can use this online version if you are in a hurry:
http://www.00bug.com/native2ascii.html

Regards